# Activating function on click with tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, nmap

I have a function that creates radio buttons:

```
def scan_networks():
    net_scan = nmap.PortScanner()
    net_scan.scan(hosts='10.0.0.0/24', arguments='-sn')
    network_scan_window = Tk()
    for i, host in enumerate(net_scan.all_hosts()):
        targetable_hosts_label = Label(text="Targetable Hosts:").grid(row=0)
        hosts_radio = Radiobutton(network_scan_window, value=host, text=host).grid(row=1, column=i)
    network_scan_window.mainloop()
```

I need to call a function when clicking on one of the hosts radio with it's host.

So lets say the function returned a bunch of radio buttons with different ip's
I need to call function x with the parameter of the value of the radio button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with [Radiobuttons](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112013840/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm), you should use a [variable](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112025221/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) to group the radiobuttons together and to keep track of the current value. You can use the `command` option of the Radiobutton to have a function be called when making a selection and get the value of the variable to get the current selection:

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback():
    print(v.get())

root = tk.Tk()

list = ['one', 'two', 'three']

v = tk.StringVar()
v.set(list[0])

for value in list:
    tk.Radiobutton(root, value=value, text=value, variable=v, command=callback).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So 'v' is the name of the group and v.get is the value?
I managed to work it out with command and it executes my function, thanks!

Comment: `v` is the `StringVar` object. All Radiobuttons that have the same object as `variable` are in the same "group", meaning only one of these Radiobuttons can be selected at a time. You can get the current value of `v` with `v.get()` but you can also change the selected Radiobutton with something like `v.set('two')`. You should be able to get most of the information you need from the two pages I linked.